# Select query with where clause extremely slows down if applied on second table's columns

Tags: database, performance, t-sql, join, view

I have two tables: A and B. And there is a VIEW consists of LEFT JOIN statement of those two tables. I'm running SELECT query on that VIEW with where clause. If filters are applied only on table A's columns, the query runs fast. But, if I add any B's column into the filter (regardless of data type) the query execution time dramatically increases from 0.5 second to 50-60 seconds. So what causes the problem?

Comment: You really should show your query, as well as the `EXPLAIN` output. Chances are you just need to add an index on whatever the `WHERE` contains, but we can't help without more info.

Comment: Please write your table schema and query.

Comment: Please also post the execution plan

Answer (score 0):

try to add that filter condition in ON clause
eg
Select col1, col2
From A LEFT JOIN B ON (A.x = B.p and B.q = ?)
WHERE A.m = ?

I assume B.q = ? is your filter condition which making your query become slow

If the above solution not solve your problem then create index on column in B table which is used for filtering